# Cannot get htmlproofer to ignore missing image alt tags

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm running [htmlproofer](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer) to check a WIP Jekyll-generated site that currently has a lot of missing image tags. I'd like to ignore the for the time being until other broken links are resolved. I expected this pattern would work:

```
bundle exec htmlproofer ./_site --assume-extension --empty-alt-ignore --disable-external
```

However it still returns errors for missing alt tags. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing `--alt-ignore '/.*/'` instead of `--empty-alt-ignore` should help you.
`--empty-alt-ignore` is for ignoring `alt` tags set to `""`